# In Jmeter i am able to test websites through mobile but unable to test mobile apps

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

this is the error i get while trying to test mobile application

[image]
[image]

Unable to find the reason. tried this: `server.rmi.ssl.disable=true` still doesn't work.other actions are recorded but not the mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `server.rmi.ssl.disable=true` property simply disables encryption of data transfer between master and slaves in [distributed testing mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), it's not connected to recording by any means

1. First of all you will need to import JMeter's certificate onto your mobile device. See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [JMeter user manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for more details.
2. Second, depending on the mobile operating system you will need to:

   - for iOS - [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477) for the JMeter's certificate
   - for Android (and I think this is your case) - amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) to allow intercepting of the SSL traffic like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)

   Chrome on Android trusts certificates installed by the users so you will be able to record browser networking activity but when it comes to other applications you need to explicitly allow it.

Comment: any suggestions for pen test ,free tool? for mobile apps @Dmitri T